# Android: Yahoo Weather App Horizontal Scroll-view Effect?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know what the Android implementation is of this type of scrolling that you see in the Yahoo Weather App. Here is a video example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-q_yetkpik

Any examples or ideas on how to implement this would sincerely help this poor lost soul!

Thank you

Comment: Might be something similar to swipe views on a ViewPager but with hidden tabs.

Comment: The basic answer is simple: use a ViewPager with ScrollViews as page content. The implementation can be tricky though, depending on how close to what the video shows you want your app to be. I think you should start implementing this and once questions arise ask them here. As it is right now your question is too general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use that library https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerLibrary, it's very easy to use, and it worked for me

[demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zEOUWY9Hvo)

Answer (score 2):

You should separate two different things here:

**The horizontal scrolling**
As you swipe your way through the viewpager, the background moves slower than the content does. 
This effect can be achieved with the [ParallaxPagerLibrary](https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerLibrary)

**The vertical scrolling**
As you swipe up, the background image blurs away, making the "swiped up" content more visible to the user. [This post](http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/) explains it all and also provides a library.

But if you want it even better, someone wrote a simple "clone" of this weather app https://github.com/MoshDev/LikeYahooWeather

Answer (score 1):

They customized `ViewPager`, the widget is called `WeatherViewPager` that it's unfortunately unavailable, looks like a `ViewPager` with a sort of parallax

You may take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos

it's a collection of usable opensource libraries

e.g. `Utils->Paralloid` or `Utils->ParallaxScroll`